# How can I track all trades at an exchange such as GDAX

Tags: exchanges, tracking

Can I track all trades on an exchange, not just my own. Is it possible to assign a trade to an anonymous figure then continue to track that figure?

Answer (score 1):

"Can I track all trades on an exchange, not just my own" yes. visit https://docs.gdax.com/#get-trades for additional information. this trades are afaik anonymous so you can not track who did which trade.

Comment: I was able to get client ID.... this is the person and it does not seem to change.

{
"client_oid": "d1a28cd9-4bee-4288-a11d-9d7af8d497f7",
"order_id": "a50d10fc-8e0b-4a1f-bd53-2fee46519711",
"order_type": "limit",
"price": "809.14000000",
"product_id": "ETH-USD",
"sequence": 3580533179,
"side": "sell",
"size": "6.00000000",
"time": "2018-05-05T09:18:40.274000Z",
"type": "received"
}

Comment: Anonymous is ok -- I'm tracking Client ID